# Cauchy's Integral Formula?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Say you have a function with a single discontinuity (a simple pole). Now say you have want to compute the line integral of a simple closed curve around the discontinuity. You can deform the curve into a smaller and smaller circle around the discontinuity until it's infinitesimally small. And since it's infinitesimally small shouldn't its contribution to the line integral be zero? So shouldn't the line integral evaluate to zero even with a simple pole inside of it?

An analogy: You can integrate a single variable function over a region with finite discontinuities since the discontinuities have an infinitesimal contribution and so don't change anything. Since when do infinitesimal quantities affect the total quantity?

This is obviously not true though since the line integral actually evaluates to the residue of the function at that pole $\dot{} 2\pi\dot{}i$

What's the problem with my logic?

Comment: You make the curve smaller and smaller but $\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}$ is bigger and bigger.

Comment: The $z-z_0$ part is making it bigger right? $1/(z-z_0)$ is odd though so shouldn't any effect it has on $f(z)$ cancel out through symmetry?

Comment: Note that $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z-z_0}=2\pi i \ne 0$ for  $\gamma(t)=z_0+re^{it},$ where $r$ is arbitrary small.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a formal argument but I think of it like this. Since the function is analytic everywhere else in the region bound by the simple closed contour $C$, those points do not contribute to the line integral. That means the simple pole (or any other singular point) contributes an "infinite" volume to the integral (i.e. the "height" at the singularity is infinity, multiplied by the infinitesimal area "brings it down" to a finite number). So no matter how small you shrink your contour, the singularity is always contained inside the contour, and thus the line integral is non-zero. Again, this is an informal geometric answer to your question, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

plausible assumptions often mislead us. maybe focus first on a very simple case - the line integral of $f(z) = \frac1{z}$ round a circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin.

on the circle we have $z = re^{i\theta}$, so we may write $dz=ir\theta e^{i\theta}$. so
$$
\oint \frac{dz}{z} =  \oint \frac{ ire^{i\theta} d\theta}{re^{i\theta} } = 2\pi i
$$
the implications of this simple computation are quite profound, so  whatever effort it takes to thoroughly absorb it is time well spent!